# Can not upload image to API with Postman (File field is required) .NET6

Tags: postman, .net-6.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to send an image file to api controller with postman. I am working with .Net 6.

The problem is an error always appears as in the image, [postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL8bg.png)

That is my code

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers

public class Image
{
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CarImagesController : ControllerBase
{      
    [HttpPost("add")]
    public IActionResult Add([FromForm] Image file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

If it is eligible to use, I want to change argument of Add method, i mean

```
public IActionResult Add([FromForm] IFormFile file)
```

and I want to delete Image class after that change.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, I create a sample using them, they all works well. The issue might relate that when using Postman, the key value contains spaces, such as `file` .

You can check the following screenshot: when using `file` key, everything works well, but if using `file` (with spaces), it will show the 400 error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your code is all fine but you have an issue in postman. Check the formField key `file`. It has whitespace bcz you pressed enter there. Just remove any extra space and it should work.

I know it sounds stupid, but that's the issue. Postman takes whitespace and new lines seriously as key and values.

[image: postman field]

see the arrow and ... , that's the indicator.